# onConfigureFailed: android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl@1bceb33

Tags: android

I am trying to implement android.hardware.camera2 api to take picture and display I have referred to https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/ this tutorial.

I am getting error:

> onConfigureFailed: android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl@1bceb33

on Nokia 6.1 plus (Android 9,api level 28). I am new to Android development.

this is createCaptureSession() and onConfigureFailed() @Override method every time onConfigureFailed call

```
 cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Comment: If this question might be helped by readers looking at (the relevant bit of) your code, please add it to the question itself. It does not matter if it is in the tutorial - that link may change or fail in the future, and we'd like the question to survive after that point.

Comment: @halfer sorry halfer i am also new to stack overflow  i have edit my question please see this